# Rails 2.3.8 validation doesn't work from console (valid? always returns true)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've recently updated my rails app from rails 2.3.3 to 2.3.8 and faced such a problem: all model validations work fine in browser, but completely ignored when testing them using **.valid?** method from console. This happen to all my models. 
For example, my **Company** model has:

```
class Company < Content
...

 # Validation

  before_validation     :ensure_token_existance

  validates_presence_of :name,
                        :address,
                        :employee_count,
                        :category_ids,
                        :region_ids,
                        :phone,
                        :email,
                        :if => Proc.new { |company| company.step?(1) },
                        :message => "required field"

  validates_presence_of :description,
                        :if => Proc.new { |company| company.step?(2) },
                        :message => "required field"

  after_update :cache_sweeper

...
```

Now testing validation of Company instance from console:

```
$ script/console 
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
>> c = Company.new
=> #<Company id: nil, account_id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, employee_count: nil, logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, moderation: nil, token: nil, expired_at: nil, address: nil, phone: nil, fax: nil, email: nil, site: nil, delta: true, position: nil, major_company: false, wizard_step: 0, manager_id: nil, org_form: "", robots: nil, language: nil>
>> c.valid?
=> true
>> c.errors
=> #<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x105004848 @errors=#<OrderedHash {}>, @base=#<Company id: nil, account_id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, employee_count: nil, logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, moderation: "draft", token: "mYoXPgNYwxBmdCTI", expired_at: nil, address: nil, phone: nil, fax: nil, email: nil, site: nil, delta: true, position: nil, major_company: false, wizard_step: 0, manager_id: nil, org_form: "", robots: nil, language: nil>>
>> c.save
=> true
>> c.save!
=> true
```

I've checked http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#when-does-validation-happen :

> The following methods trigger validations, and will save the object to
>   the database only if the object is valid:
>
> ```
> create
> create!
> save
> save!
> update
> update_attributes
> update_attributes!
> ```
>
> The bang versions (e.g. save!) raise an exception if the record is
>   invalid. The non-bang versions don’t: save and update_attributes
>   return false, create and update just return the object/s.

Can anyone help me to figure out what's wrong here, please ? =)

Comment: Would your ```:if => Proc.new { |company| company.step?(1) }``` be causing the issue? as I don't see you setting the company.step in the console. So that might be causing the validation to be overlooked since it's not on that step.

Comment: Thx @Koby, that really caused the issue, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validations are dependent on the company being in a certain step. You never set this property in the console. What happens if you try:

```
c = Company.new
c.step = 1
c.valid?
```

I'm just guessing that the `step?` method simply does an equality test on the attribute `step`. If not, do whatever it takes so your model satisfies `step?(1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Derek, that really solved an issue. Seems like I've spent too much time upgrading my app to 2.3.8 to miss that...